# The difference between have done + will or would

Tags: grammar

Only one or two people have objected that the students will drive too fast.

Why not use would instead of will in the sentence above?

Comment: Normally one would say, "Only one or two people have objected to them driving too fast."

Comment: Can the person voting down tell me the reason, for I can not ask question in this forum?

Comment: @aparente001: That's if the students have *already* been seen driving too fast.  (Also, *their driving* is better than *them driving*.)

Comment: @AntonSherwood - In my version, we don't know that they actually have been driving too fast.  In yours, there is an assumption that they have been.

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, either can be used, depending on context.  If the discussion is about opening a new freeway near the school, and it's pretty much a "done deal", then it's just a question of whether the students will or won't drive too fast.

But if we're speaking of a proposed law change then it may be implied that the students **would** drive too fast *if the law is passed*.

Comment: My English is so poor that I can not understand your words well. May you retell me them in a simpler words?

Comment: @Y.zeng - Please visit our sister site, ELL, English Language Learners.  It is better and more helpful for your level.  You will like it.  (If you were to visit it, you would like it.)

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks very much.

Comment: If it happened in the past, should I replace **will** by **would**?

Answer (score 1):

Because the main clause is expressed in a present tense. Compare:

> Only one or two people **object** that the students **will** drive too fast (*simple present tense*)

> Only one or two people **have objected** that the students **will** drive too fast (*present perfect*)

> Only one or two people **objected** that the students **would** drive too fast (*simple past tense*)

EDIT The use of `will`/`would` in phrases like those is slightly more nuanced.

`will` can express future action, but also present intent or habit, so it can be interpreted in two ways:

> Only one or two people **have objected** that the students **will** drive too fast when the law is passed. (people are worried that, once the law is implemented, students will drive too fast in the future)

> Only one or two people **have complained** that the students **will** drive too fast just for thrills these days. (people noticed that it is the students' habit to drive too fast, simply because they like it)

If we switch to the past tense, *will* becomes *would* in both sentences (although using *will* in the second instance would probably still be understood):

> Only one or two people **objected** that the students **would** drive too fast when the law was passed.

> Only one or two people **complained** that the students **would** drive too fast just for thrills those days.

`would`, in turn, may express a hypothetical scenario, but also a past habit:

> Only one or two people **have objected** that the students **would** drive too fast if the new law was passed. (it's still not decided whether the law will be implemented, so it's only a hypothesis)

> Only one or two people **have objected** that the students **would** drive too fast the last time the law is passed, so they are likely to do it again. (people are worried that things will turn out exactly the same as in the past; *would* means *used to* here)

If we switch to past tense, the use of *would* doesn't change:

> Only one or two people **complained** that the students **would** drive too fast if the new law was passed.

> Only one or two people **objected** that the students **would** drive too fast the last time the law **had been passed**, so they **were** likely to do it again.

Comment: Is this wrong: **Only one or two people have objected that the students would drive too fast.**?

Comment: No, it's not wrong at all. Depending on the context, the meaning might be slightly different, though. `Would` usually describes a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: But if the students drove too fast in the past, may we say: **Only one or two people have objected that the students would drive too fast.**?  Because it happened in the past, so I think the **would** should be used, not **will**? And where am I wrong?

Comment: Well, if the students drove too fast *in the past*, why would people object to it *now*? Also, if they drove too fast in the past, then you would use neither 'will' nor 'would', you would state the facts, not hypothetical scenarios or future predictions, e. g. : *Only one or two people have objeced that the students drove too fast in the past, so they are likely to do it again*.

Comment: It just shows the attitude of the people for recent years.  I guess.

Comment: I'll try to expand on my answer later today and list all the possible options and their meaning

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: @Y.zeng see my updated answer

Comment: Only one or two people have objected that the students would drive too fast if the new law was passed. (it's still not decided whether the law will be implemented, so it's only a hypothesis). May you tell me why not say,"**the new law were passed**? As it's only a hypothesis.

Comment: Only one or two people **have objected** that the students would drive too fast the last time the law **had been passed**, so they **were** likely to do it again. May you tell me why use present perfect tense in the main clause, and use past perfect tense in the conditional adverbial clause? Why use **were**?

Comment: It was a nasty copy-paste, See my updated answer

Comment: Regarding was/were - use *were* if you want to be super correct. *Was* is also acceptable, though

Comment: Thanks very much.